# Python splinter select by tag attribute

Tags: python, splinter

I am messing around with some web scraping using Splinter but have this issue. The html basically has loads of `li` only some of which I am interested in. The ones I am interested in have a bid value. Now, I know for Beautiful Soup I can do

```
tab = browser.find_by_css('li', {'bid': '18663145091'})
```

but this doesn't seem to work for splinter. I get an error saying:

> find_by_css() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

This is a sample of my html:

```
<li class="rugby" bid="18663145091">
          <span class="info">
           <div class="points">
            12
           </div>
           <img alt="Leinster" height="19" src="..Leinster" width="26"/>
          </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using `find_by_css()` method as if it was a `BeautifulSoup` method. Instead, provide a valid *CSS selector* checking the value of the `bid` attribute:

```
tab = browser.find_by_css('li[bid=18663145091]')
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine them for example `tab = browser.find_by_css('li[bid=18663145091, name="asd"])`

Comment: @19421608 sure, the correct syntax is: `li[bid=18663145091][name=asd]`.